# How to exclude category ID from Looper in Wordpress

Tags: php, categories, shortcode

I'm trying to exclude 2 (and potentially more) ID's from my loop, that displays all categories that have posts. The category ID's i'm currently trying to exclude are 1 and 19. I'm very new to PHP but have previously been able to fix my issues by searching on the forum but nothing so far has worked.

```php
// Function to create shortcode of all categories
function my_categories_shortcode() { 
 
// extracting categories
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
)

?><div class="categorylist">
 <?php foreach (get_categories( $args ) as $cat ) : ?>

<a class="categorylink" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
<h3 class="categoryname"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></h3></a>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
 <?php
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('showcategories', 'my_categories_shortcode');
```

What should i add, to exclude categories?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Thanks, i solved this by adding a continue function as mentioned by Tom Nowell. I have also added the hint that this is a string to the function:

```php
// Function to create shortcode of all categories
function my_categories_shortcode() : string { 
 
// extracting categories
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
)

?><div class="categorylist">
 <?php foreach (get_categories( $args ) as $cat ) : 
    if ($cat->term_id == 19) {
        continue;
    }
 ?>

<a class="categorylink" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
<h3 class="categoryname"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></h3></a>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
 <?php
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('showcategories', 'my_categories_shortcode');
```

Comment: hardcoding IDs means your website will break if you ever move it, or if those categories are deleted and recreated for whatever reason. At the very minimum use hardcoded slugs so you can recreate a term if that happens without changing code.

Comment: @TomJNowell Adding the ": string" as done in my edit stops the rest of the page from loading, could you explain what i've done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Functions that have `: string` must return a string, but as I mentioned in my answer, your shortcode is built incorrectly and does not return its content as a string. Shortcodes can't echo or output directly, but that's what your shortcode function does, which is wrong and incorrect. Shortcodes that output directly via `?>stuff<?php` or `echo 'stuff';` break REST APIs, XMLRPC, RSS feeds, they don't work inside nested shortcodes, and they appear at the start of a post, not the location you put the shortcode. Do not directly echo or output HTML in a shortcode! Put it in a variable and return it

Comment: See the example and re-read my answer, it includes examples demonstrating the difference, and comment on my answer instead to reply to it, especially the very last sentence

Comment: in addition to the comments and answers by @tom-j-nowell, have you checked the documentation of the function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/ that there is an 'exclude' parameter; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already in your code:

```php
 <?php foreach (get_categories( $args ) as $cat ) : ?>

<a class="categorylink" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
```

More specifically:

```php
 <?php foreach (get_categories( $args ) as $cat ) : ?>

...get_category_link($cat->term_id)...
```

That `term_id` is the ID of the category, so just test if it matches one of your undesired IDs and `continue;` to skip to the next one.

---

However, there is an unrelated but super critical mistake in your code. Shortcodes do not echo/output directly. They need to return their output in a string. This shortcode will break a lot of things, and will appear in the wrong place.

Remember:

```php
function brokenshortcode() {
    ?><p>I am an awful shortcode that breaks lots of things</p><?php
}
add_shortcode( 'broken', 'brokenshortcode' );
```

```php
function niceshortcode() : string {
    return '<p>I am a good well behaved shortcode</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'nice', 'niceshortcode' );
```

You can enforce this by type hinting the function like this:

```php
function my_categories_shortcode() : string {
```

Now the function will cause a PHP fatal if you make this mistake